# Change order of checkout process

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

I have a custom module(now just overriding the template files to customize the default checkout structure) that overrides the default checkout process. I want to change the default order of **checkout process** to Order `Review`,`Sign In`,`Shipping`,`Payment`.

I have tried by editing `opcheckout.js` file. But I can't see any change in its order.
How is it possible to change its order? Please help..

I have tried to override the block file:app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Abstract.php to app/code/local/Company/Custcheckout/Block/Onepage/Abstract.php

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Custcheckout>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Company_Custcheckout>
    </modules> 
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <checkout>
                <rewrite>
                    <onepage_abstract>Company_Custcheckout_Block_Onepage_Abstract</onepage_abstract>

                </rewrite>
            </checkout>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <checkout>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Company_Custcheckout before="Mage_Checkout">Company_Custcheckout</Company_Custcheckout>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </checkout>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <Custcheckout>
                    <file>custcheckout/custcheckout.xml</file>
                </Custcheckout>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend> 
</config>
```

I have changed `opcheckout.js` file (line number:40) as

```
this.steps = ['login', 'review', 'shipping', 'shipping_method', 'billing', 'payment'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to override this function `_getStepCodes()` from `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Abstract.php` to your local codepool

```
protected function _getStepCodes()
{
    return array('login', 'billing', 'shipping', 'shipping_method', 'payment', 'review');
}
```

Comment: I have tried, but no luck.I have added the code. Could you please check.

Comment: look my update, the function looks like this

Comment: I have used the same code in app/code/local/Company/Custcheckout/Block/Onepage/Abstract.php    <?php

class Company_Custcheckout_Block_Onepage_Abstract extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Get checkout steps codes
     *
     * @return array
     */

 protected function _getStepCodes()
 {
     return array('login', 'billing', 'shipping', 'shipping_method', 'payment', 'review');
 }
}
But not changing the order.

Comment: Try to change `Custcheckout` with Checkout in folder and class

Comment: Not working with your code. app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Abstract.php is abstract class. When I googled, found that "cannot rewrite abstract classes".

Comment: Still not able to override abstract class

Comment: Yes sure we can't rewrite but overriding yes, And I told you to override it :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62782/discussion-between-v-p-and-prince).